# webpackJsonp is not defined - VueJS

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

We are working on one large scale app, and one part of app is using the vuejs, but for some reasons, this vuejs part of app doesn't work and we got this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Our webpack.config.js file, looks like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path    = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['./node_modules', './resources/assets/scripts']
  },

  entry: {
    // Commons and Libraries
    common: ['jquery', './resources/assets/scripts/main.js'],

    // Chunks per Page
    home: './resources/assets/scripts/home.js',
    blog: './resources/assets/scripts/blog.js',
    about: './resources/assets/scripts/about.js',
    contact: './resources/assets/scripts/contact.js',
    shop: './resources/assets/scripts/shop.js', // This is VueJS chunk
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets/js'),
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:     /\.js$/,
        loader:   'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      { test: /jquery\.js$/, loader: 'expose?$' },
      { test: /jquery\.js$/, loader: 'expose?jQuery' },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
            // limit for base64 inlining in bytes
            limit: 10000,
            // custom naming format if file is larger than
            // the threshold
            name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
          },
        },
        {
      // Use SVG File loader
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'svg-url-loader'
    }
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("package.json", ["main"])
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      minChunks: 2
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true, preserveComments: 'license'})
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late for you, but based on [this thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368) on the Webpack forums, it looks like there's a conflict between this line in your entry:

```
common: ['jquery', './resources/assets/scripts/main.js'],
```

and this line:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common',
  minChunks: 2
}),
```

You're essentially telling Webpack to create two files named Common, so it's creating a conflict. You can see [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368#issuecomment-49552716) for a more detailed explanation. There's too much context specific information to copy>paste the details here, but that thread/comment has some good information in it for getting in deeper.